# I can't make a sine wave with wave library in Python

Tags: python, wave

I want it to generate a .wav file with a simply sine wave, but it gives me a strange, curved wave.

[image]

```
import wave, struct
import random
import math

output = "audio.wav"
audio = []
while 1:
    for i in range(1,1000):
      audio.append(int(10000*math.cos(i)))

    wav_file=wave.open(output,"w")
    wav_file.setparams((1, 2, 48000.0, 63360 , "NONE", "not compressed"))
    for sample in audio:
      wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack("h", sample))
    wav_file.close()
    break
```

What to do?

Comment: That happens when you sample a sine wave with a finite sampling rate. Increase the sampling rate or reduce the frequency of the sine wave. As long as the frequency of the sine wave is below half the sampling rate, it's not a problem due to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem.